# How to GROUP BY eloquent in <select>

Tags: php, eloquent

I want to have unique mounths in SELECT. I find out i have to use GROUP BY. But it doesnt work this way:

```
 @foreach($months as $month)
       <option value="{{ $month->id }}">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($month
->date)
->format(' F ')
->groupBy('date') }}</option>    
 @endforeach
```

How to use groupBy in this way? Because it looks like this right now without GROUP BY:
[image: Because it looks like this right now without GROUP BY]

My Laravel Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all(['name', 'id']);
    $months = RouteInfo::all(['date', 'id']);

    return view('admin.index', compact('users', $users, 'months', $months));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Group by only work in eloquent object. You should add function group by to RouteInfo and formatter select date. But you will another problems, in group by function the first element get it is id to value in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just filter items before show

```
@php
$uniqueMonth = [];
  foreach($months as $key=>$month){
     $month = Carbon\Carbon::parse($month->date);
     $uniqueMonth[$month->format('m')] = $month->format(' F ');
  }
  ksort($uniqueMonth); // sorting months
@endphp

@foreach($uniqueMonth as $key=>$month)
   <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $month }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get Error: Call to a member function groupBy() on string (View:

Comment: i fixed answer. Sry

Comment: I have 9 record of November and all of them showing. It have to show just unique values.

Comment: You can try fixed version

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, within your controller.

```
$months = RouteInfo::all(['date', 'id'])->groupBy(function($month) {
    return Carbon::parse($month->date)->format('F');
});
```

Then within your view

```
@foreach($months as $month)
    <option>{{ $month }}</option>
@endforeach
```

This is untested, please let me know if it works for you or if there are any errors.

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in

Comment: Try removing the ``get()``

Comment: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: What ID are you trying to get? Currently the output should be a collection grouped per month, and within those months there should be the items for those months.

Comment: Still doesnt work correct. Right now in SELECT show: [{"date":"2017-11-17 00:00:00" , "id":6}]